# Can I use multiple controllers when using resource controllers?

Tags: laravel-9

I have created a resource controller(devices, DeviceController).
Now I want to add in the devices.edit a dropdown menu from another table with which the model device has a relationship.

I tried to create a DropdownController which returns the status of the devices but the controller does not reach the view although I created a route.

But when I send the statusse via DeviceController then it works.

My question is do I have to send everything via the DeviceController or can I split it up?

The error is Undefined variable $status

```
//DropController
public function show(){

    $status = Status::all();
    return view('devices.edit',compact('status'));
}

// web.php
Route::get('devices.edit',[\App\Http\Controllers\DropController::class,'show']);
Route::resource('devices', DeviceController::class);


//devices.edit
<select name="ddStatus">
    @foreach($status as $state)
        <option value="{{ $state->id }}">{{ $state->Status_Name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select></p>
```

If I send the statuses in the DeviceController then it works, but I would like to manage the dropdown with a separate controller. Or is it ok to send such things also in the DeviceController? Because I thought you should separate that

Comment: Rename the custom `devices.edit` to something else. Resource controller already has the route with the same name but since custom route is above in sequence, it will be kicked in while the resource route will be ignored.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you 100%, I have to give a ->name('xxx') at the end of the route I have defined myself and how do I address this route from the controller?

Comment: I may have misunderstood. So let me ask this, `\App\Http\Controllers\DropController::class,'show'` already has a corresponding route as you are implementing `Route::resource('devices', DeviceController::class);` Why you are declaring a custom route for the same method?

Comment: Because I would like to use several controllers for this one view so that the DeviceController is not overfilled unnecessarily and so that it stays clean. And my thought now was to create a second controller which handles the dropdown stuff and therefore I need this route I assumed

Comment: Two routes for same method in controller is redundancy in itself.

Comment: I am not sure if we mean the same thing, for example I want to create a drop down in the devices.edit but not send the data via the devicecontroller instead I want to create an extra controller for the dropdown which gives the data to the devices.edit.

Comment: if it is just for the dropdown, then why not use `ServiceProviders` with `View::composer()`?

Comment: Because I have no idea what you mean xD It's my first project with laravel so I'm not in it yet but I wanted to do some things right after convention.  Now I just kept everything in the DeviceController because that's working the way I want it to. Thanks for taking your time

Comment: View composer in simple terms, is something which enables you to directly fetch the data from the models whenever you use that view (no need to pass the data from the controller to the view). It is convenient in many occasions such as drop downs. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#view-composers

Comment: Damn looks like this is exactly what I was looking for,but now I have already done everything as described earlier. Thank you but I will keep this in mind